# Automapper resolvers performance

Tags: c#, automapper

As I am working on a large project involving multiple DTOs and mappings between them, I was a little concerned about performance of various ways to resolve and map values between two classes and a third source. So I have written this small program to test various ways to map some common properties from a supplied variable.

```
#region

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using AutoMapper;

#endregion

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mapper.Reset();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Starting");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Test1();
                Test2();
                Test3();
                Test4();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }

        private static void Test1()
        {
            Mapper.Reset();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Quote, Policy>()
                .ForMember(m => m.Id, o => o.Ignore())
                .ForMember(m => m.Number, o => o.Ignore())
                .ForMember(m => m.AuditName, o => o.ResolveUsing<UserNameResolver>())
                .ForMember(m => m.AuditTime, o => o.ResolveUsing<AuditTimeResolver>());
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            Mapper.Configuration.Seal();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                UserSetting us = new UserSetting {UserName = "Test", ExecTime = DateTime.Now};
                Quote q = new Quote {Id = i, Description = i.ToString("0000000")};
                Policy p = Mapper.Map<Policy>(q, o => o.Items[Constants.UserSetting] = us);
            }
        }

        private static void Test2()
        {
            Mapper.Reset();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Quote, Policy>()
                .ForMember(m => m.Id, o => o.Ignore())
                .ForMember(m => m.Number, o => o.Ignore())
                .ForMember(m => m.AuditName, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.Context.Options.GetRequestUserName()))
                .ForMember(m => m.AuditTime, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.Context.Options.GetRequestExecTime()));
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            Mapper.Configuration.Seal();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                UserSetting us = new UserSetting {UserName = "Test", ExecTime = DateTime.Now};
                Quote q = new Quote {Id = i, Description = i.ToString("0000000")};
                Policy p = Mapper.Map<Policy>(q, o => o.Items[Constants.UserSetting] = us);
            }
        }

        private static void Test3()
        {
            Mapper.Reset();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Quote, Policy>()
                .ForMember(m => m.Id, o => o.Ignore())
                .ForMember(m => m.Number, o => o.Ignore())
                .ForMember(m => m.AuditName, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.Context.Options.GetCastRequestUserName()))
                .ForMember(m => m.AuditTime, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.Context.Options.GetCastRequestExecTime()));
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            Mapper.Configuration.Seal();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                UserSetting us = new UserSetting {UserName = "Test", ExecTime = DateTime.Now};
                Quote q = new Quote {Id = i, Description = i.ToString("0000000")};
                Policy p = Mapper.Map<Policy>(q, o => o.Items[Constants.UserSetting] = us);
            }
        }

        private static void Test4()
        {
            Mapper.Reset();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Quote, Policy>()
                .ForMember(m => m.Id, o => o.Ignore())
                .ForMember(m => m.Number, o => o.Ignore())
                .ForMember(m => m.AuditName,
                    o =>
                        o.ResolveUsing<SingletonUserNameResolver>()
                            .ConstructedBy(() => SingletonUserNameResolver.Instance))
                .ForMember(m => m.AuditTime,
                    o =>
                        o.ResolveUsing<SingletonAuditTimeResolver>()
                            .ConstructedBy(() => SingletonAuditTimeResolver.Instance));
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            Mapper.Configuration.Seal();    

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                UserSetting us = new UserSetting {UserName = "Test", ExecTime = DateTime.Now};
                Quote q = new Quote {Id = i, Description = i.ToString("0000000")};
                Policy p = Mapper.Map<Policy>(q, o => o.Items[Constants.UserSetting] = us);
            }
        }
    }

    internal class UserSetting
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExecTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class Policy
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string AuditName { get; set; }
        public DateTime AuditTime { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Quote
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string AuditName { get; set; }
        public DateTime AuditTime { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static string GetRequestUserName(this MappingOperationOptions options)
        {
            // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
            return (options.Items[Constants.UserSetting] as UserSetting).UserName;
        }

        public static DateTime GetRequestExecTime(this MappingOperationOptions options)
        {
            // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
            return (options.Items[Constants.UserSetting] as UserSetting).ExecTime;
        }

        public static string GetCastRequestUserName(this MappingOperationOptions options)
        {
            // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
            return (options.Items.Values.Cast<UserSetting>().First()).UserName;
        }

        public static DateTime GetCastRequestExecTime(this MappingOperationOptions options)
        {
            // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
            return (options.Items.Values.Cast<UserSetting>().First()).ExecTime;
        }
    }

    public static class Constants
    {
        public const string UserSetting = "UserSetting";
    }

    public class UserNameResolver : IValueResolver
    {
        #region IValueResolver Members

        public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
        {
            return source.New((source.Context.Options.Items[Constants.UserSetting] as UserSetting).UserName);
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class SingletonUserNameResolver : IValueResolver
    {
        private static Lazy<SingletonUserNameResolver> _instance =
            new Lazy<SingletonUserNameResolver>(() => new SingletonUserNameResolver());

        public static SingletonUserNameResolver Instance
        {
            get { return _instance.Value; }
        }

        #region IValueResolver Members

        public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
        {
            return source.New((source.Context.Options.Items[Constants.UserSetting] as UserSetting).UserName);
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class AuditTimeResolver : IValueResolver
    {
        #region IValueResolver Members

        public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
        {
            return source.New((source.Context.Options.Items[Constants.UserSetting] as UserSetting).ExecTime);
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class SingletonAuditTimeResolver : IValueResolver
    {
        private static Lazy<SingletonAuditTimeResolver> _instance =
            new Lazy<SingletonAuditTimeResolver>(() => new SingletonAuditTimeResolver());

        public static SingletonAuditTimeResolver Instance
        {
            get { return _instance.Value; }
        }

        #region IValueResolver Members

        public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
        {
            return source.New((source.Context.Options.Items[Constants.UserSetting] as UserSetting).ExecTime);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

In Test1, I use custom value resolvers to grab user name and execution time, standard auditing fields, from the Items dictionary of Context.Options property. In Test2, I bypass the resolvers and go after the dictionary directly with an extension method on MappingOperationsOptions. In Test3, I also go after the same dictionary but with a LINQ generic Cast, knowing that there is only one object of the UserSetting type.

When ran with the profiling assistance of RedGate's ANTS Profiler, Test3 took total of 559.667ms, Test2 took 565.783ms, while Test1 took 1752.538ms. As I dug deeper, it turns out that the constructors for the custom value resolvers are called for every iteration of the test, one hundred thousand times each. Is there any possibility of avoiding those costly (1-4ms in a production scenario) calls. Or am I missing something obvious?

**Update**

First, the code has been updated, to actually perform the mapping. Then I have added a Singleton anti-pattern to construct the custom resolvers only once. Here are results:

```
Test1 - 3189.186ms 
Test2 - 1297.870ms
Test3 - 1807.477ms
Test4 - 1381.149ms
```

So the extension method on the dictionary remains the fastest, but the singleton resolver is close second.

Tests were executed on a Lenovo ThinkStation C20 with 24GB of RAM and dual quad-core Xeon 2.27GHz CPUs.

**Update 2**
Not sure if I had met the standards of performance benchmarking outlined by Mr.Peer, but here are new results, after changing build to Release and "warming up" the tests like so:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Reset();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Warming up");
        RunTests();
        Console.WriteLine("Starting");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            RunTests();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }

    private static void RunTests()
    {
        Test1();
        Test2();
        Test3();
        Test4();
    }
```

Results (time with Children in ms):

```
Test1 3405.485
Test2 1620.115
Test3 2005.364
Test4 1499.720
```

After Visual Studio restart

```
Test1 3654.204
Test2 1568.931
Test3 1901.894
Test4 2080.056
```

Thanks for all the help I have received so far.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difference betwee your two tests?

Comment: I'm sorry, 1-4ms?  I think your math is off there.  If it was taking 1-4ms at 1 million calls, that would be 1000-4000 seconds (not ms).  Are you really doing million of calls per second that this kind of performance is really that critical?  - actually looking at your code, it's 100,000 iterations, not 1 million

Comment: I don't know what kind of machine you are running this on, but it only takes 704ms total to run the entire program.  I also only see about 101ms for the first test, 68ms for the second, and 71 for the third (the rest of the time seems to be taken up by garbage collection)

Comment: There might be something to it, Erik. Recently, a Windows 8.1 update was put on it and all of a sudden I started having performance problems in various places. Your results are most interesting.

Comment: @Darek - i'm running Windows 8.1, recently updated.. so no issue there.  Did you a) compile in release mode?  and b) your profiler's instrumentation will itself cause huge slowdowns.

Comment: Before you post any benchmark, you should try to make a good test. Please read http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one . No warmup, maybe run in debug/instrumentation, controlling the gc etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, long story short, be mindful when using custom resolvers and if needed, apply Singleton anti-pattern , or use extension methods to improve performance.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @TaW If you don't mind, I will refrain from critiquing myself.

Comment: The problem remains that this doesn't seem to answer the question at all and you haven't really resolved the issues raised about your benchmarks.